# How to ensure that all subclassing files in a directory run (and self-register themselves)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

base_foo.rb

```
class BaseFoo
  @registered_children = Hash.new

  def self.register(child_of_foo, name)
    @registered_users[name] = child_of_foo
  end
end
```

child_of_foo.rb

```
class ChildOfFoo < BaseFoo
...
end
BaseFoo.register_child(ChildOfFoo, "bar")
```

So how do I ensure that all the files like child_of_foo.rb gets loaded and will register themselves? The whole point is that base_foo.rb should not know what child files/classes exist, so I cannot require them by name

I've seen the filename enumeration and explicit `Dir["*.rb"].each { |file| load(file) }`. Is that the best way?

TIA
Cheers

Comment: Could you share any reference to provide a bit more of context ?

Answer (score 1):

`Dir["*.rb"].each { |file| load(file) }` will load all of the files in the current working directory, so is likely not what you want (the working directory may not be where the file you care about is).

Better would be to use something like `Dir.glob(File.join(__dir__, '**', '*.rb')).each { |file| require file }`

The `__dir__` will give you the directory containing the file file you run this code. The `**` means that it will look in sub directories. `File.join` takes the different parts and joins them together to make a path that works on different platforms (i.e. Windows vs *nix). Using `require` instead of `load` is generally considered better because if you run the same command multiple times it will only read the file once instead of every time it is requested.

When doing this sort of thing, I like to put my inheriting classes in a specific sub directory, so would typically have that directory listed in the `File.join`.

Another useful "trick" to note with your code, if you were to add a new method:

```
class BaseFoo
  def self.inherited(child)
    # child is the class that extended this - ChildOfFoo in your example
  end
  ...
end
```

`BaseFoo` now gets called every time a new child inherits from it without to have it call `register_child`. The downside to this is that the hook is called when the first line of the child class is read - `class ChildOfFoo < BaseFoo` - so you have no (simple) way of knowing anything about the class (such as `"bar"` in your example) other than the class' name (`ChildOfFoo`) and a pointer to its class object that you can call methods on later.

A pattern I've used is to have the `inherited` call add the classes to an array, then when they need to be used do something like `register(cls, cls.registered_name) until (cls = @my_arr.pop).nil?` where the class has a method `registered_name`